# Move MySQL database from Linux to Mac?

Tags: mysql, database-migration

I have an existing MySQL database on a Linux computer, and I need to temporarily transfer it to a computer running Mac OS X. It's a fairly small database, so it shouldn't be too hard to do, I just need to know what I need to move.

What steps do I need to take to move my data from the Linux computer to the Mac one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mysqldump to export to a file, move that file to the new machine, then use mysql to load it in, e.g.

```
$ mysqldump -p -u username > dump.sql
```

then

```
$ mysql -p -u newusername < dump.sql
```

Comment: mysqldump requires a schema name as one of the arguments. Or you need to specify one of the --databases or --all-databases flags.

Comment: I managed to get mysqldump to work after messing with some of the options.